# Angular Div layout container border collapse

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am generating a table using angular material's div layout containers. My question is simple, how do I collapse the div's borders? Please check out my jsfiddle of what I have done

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkarv/hhmkxq8y/9/)

HTML code below. Appreciate any guidance thanks.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="/template">
        <button ng-click="testFn()">Test</button>
        <div layout="row">
            <div flex ng-repeat="col in column"><span>HEADER{{$index}}</span>
                <div layout="column">
                    <div flex style="border: 1px solid black;" ng-repeat="row in [1,2,3]">{{$index}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script> 

    <form-table table-layout=tableLayout|filter:{table_id:1}></form-table>
</div>
```

My code as follows:

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hhmkxq8y/10/

Comment: I'm looking to collapse the borders not remove them. That is where there are double lines to only have single border line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ccf0sphf/13/

The result is obtained not using `border-collapse` which requires displaying `<DIV>s` as a table but instead with a mix of CSS combinators (> child selector) and `ng-class`:

```
div.col {
    border-top: solid 1px black;
}
div.col > div.box {
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    border-right: solid 1px black;
}
```

the class below is used in an ng-class to apply only to the first column:

```
div.col-first {
    border-left: solid 1px black;
}
```

This trick is necessary because there is a `<SPAN>` element as first element in the column, otherwise we could use a `first-child` pseudo-element to obtain the same result.

Comment: Fantastic this works and I've learnt more things about CSS. Thanks again.